# ExtentReport5 SparkReporter is generating only 1 report from 2 Tests when thread-count is 1

Tags: selenium, selenium-extent-report

I have to generate report in extent reporter 5, I can generate report from multiple tests, However this seems to be possible only if thread-count is set in TestNG.xml So If i have 5 test(in separate files/classes as per POM model). and thread-count is set to 5, then I am getting all 5 reports in spark.html

But I might need to run 50+ test, so I need to keep thread-count to 2. So testng will run 2 tests in parallel and once one test is done, it will proceed to third test and so on. But using only 2 as thread count 2 tests are getting reported in spark.html So how can I generate report for all 50 test keeping thread-count to 2 only?

sample testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="1" parallel="classes" name="BuildAcceptanceTesting - GP">

<listeners>  
    <listener class-name="com.TestUtil.WebEventListener"/>  
</listeners>  


  <test name ="GP pages">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.byui.gp.StudentSideTest.Test1"/>
      <class name="com.byui.gp.StudentSideTest.Test2"/>
    </classes>
    
  </test >
</suite> <!-- StudentSideTests-Parallel -->
```

Sample program:-

base.java

```
public static WebDriver initialize() {
WebDriver contr0l = null;
reportingTool(); // Adding extent reporter
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
contr0l = new ChromeDriver();
return contr0l;

public static void reportingTool() {
extent = new ExtentReports();
spark = new ExtentSparkReporter("spark.html");
spark.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
spark.config().setDocumentTitle("Report");
extent.attachReporter(spark);
}

@AfterClass
public void closeDriver(WebDriver contr0l) 
{if(contr0l != null) {
contr0l.quit();}
}
    
public void FlushExtent(WebDriver contr0l) 
{extent.flush();}
```

Test1.java

```
public class Page1 extent base{
private WebDriver contr0l;

@BeforeClass
Contr0l=base.initialize();

@Test
public void TC1(){ sysout("whatever");}

@Test
public void TC2(){ sysout("whatever");}

@AfterTest
public void kapat() {
    base.FlushExtent(contr0l);
    base.closeDriver(contr0l);
}
}
```

Test2.java

```
public class Page1 extent base{
private WebDriver contr0l;
@BeforeClass
Contr0l=base.initialize();

@Test
public void TC1(){ sysout("whatever");}

@Test
public void TC2(){ sysout("whatever");}

@AfterTest
public void kapat() {
    base.FlushExtent(contr0l);
    base.closeDriver(contr0l);
}
}
```

Comment: Is it something related to listeners?

Comment: I am also looking for way to user threadsafe to keep the thread alive until all reports are done..

Comment: I added extent.flush(); at the ilisteners level in onfinish method. its working now.